# How to add border for SliderTheme in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this slider from a card [player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK9oL.png) but I need to add border radius for right border of this slider bar [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh9zX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would match the activeTrackColor to the thumbColor:

```
SliderTheme(
    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        activeTrackColor: Colors.blue, <-- THIS -->
        trackHeight: trackHeight,
        thumbShape: const RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: trackHeight / 2),
        thumbColor: Colors.blue <-- MATCHING THIS -->
        child: Slider(...),
),
```